# Validating ftl pages with W3C Markup Validation Service

Tags: html, freemarker

Is there any way I can validate ftl pages with Markup Validation Service? I renamed my files to be .html, but I'm still getting errors on tags that are written differently. For example,
<#import "layout.ftl" as layout/> is not a valid import tag for an html file. Is there any way I can ignore ftl tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would usually validate the end result, not the source template. There is no way to remove foreign tags in the core W3C validator.